# Update list item onContextItemSelected

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter

I'm  creating a list view using `SimpleCursorAdapter`, in which list is registered for context menu ...

```
 registerForContextMenu(listView);
```

Below is onContextItemSelection

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

switch (menuItemIndex) {
    case 0:{
        //perform some action 
                //then update the adapter   
                Cursor newCursor = fetchNewCursor();
         if(newCursor .moveToFirst()){
          adapter.swapCursor(newCursor ); 
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }//if ends             
        }// case 0 ends             
        break;
 }//switch ends
}//onContextItemSelected() ends
```

this updates my whole list view, I want to add another `context menu` entry upon which I  want to update only the particular list item being (long) clicked. How can i do that...

this is how my `Cursor Adapter` looks like

```
@Override
    public View newView (Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            return viewInflater.inflate(layout, null);
    }
```

and the `bindView` method

```
@Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

        TextView t1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_one);
        TextView t2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_two);

        t1.setText(cursor.getString(...));
        t2.getString(cursor.getString(...));
}
```

regards

Answer (score 1):

You can get the selected item index from the list by calling

```
lv.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

Then update the entry in list items on that position and notify the adapter:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

switch (menuItemIndex) {
    case 0:{
        //perform some action 
                //then update the adapter   
                Cursor newCursor = fetchNewCursor();
         if(newCursor .moveToFirst()){
          adapter.swapCursor(newCursor ); 
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }//if ends             
        }// case 0 ends             
        break;
    case 1:
        <ItemType> item=lv.getSelectedItem();
        <UPdateItem>
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        break; 
 }//switch ends
}//onContextItemSelected() ends
```

Comment: what `lv.getSelectedItem();` will return?

Comment: In your adapter you set ArrayAdapter<ItemType> so getSeletedItem will return item at selected index.

Comment: im not using ArrayAdapter my adapter looks like `public class MyListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {` after getting the item how can i get the text views in it?

Comment: `lv.setAdapter(adapter); `

Comment: this should return the object of type the cursor contains. You can also get selectedIndex and get the item to update.

Comment: can i extract/cast the item to `TextView` as im doing it in `bindView` ? and then set their values like `t1.setText`?

Comment: try calling getSelectedView() instead and use findViewById on that view